# How to return on start program using while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

I got a problem with this when I choose it always exit my program and when I enter a wrong choice got to exit to?

What is wrong to my loop?  Please help with me as for looping I am having serious problems. This is a fundamental concept but my brain is old and stuck.

Could you help me understand looping to return to the start of the program.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    char choice,name[40],date[40],note[500],;
    int password;
    int ch;
    printf("\n\n\t\tMAIN MENU:");
    printf("\n\n\tADD RECORD\t[1]");
    printf("\n\tVIEW RECORD\t[2]");
    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
    printf("\n\tDELETE RECORD\t[4]");
    printf("\n\tEDIT PASSWORD\t[5]");
    printf("\n\tEXIT\t\t[6]");
    printf("\n\n\tENTER YOUR CHOICE:");
    scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch(ch)
        do{
            {
                opcase 1:
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");                      
                    break;

                case 3:
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    break;

                case 5: 
                    printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    printf("\n\n\t\tTHANK YOU FOR USING THE SOFTWARE BY:\n\n\tBIJAY PURI\n\n\tBHANU POUDEL\n\n\tNRIPASH AYER...");
                    getch();
                    exit(0);

                default:
                    printf("\nYOU ENTERED WRONG CHOICE..");
                    printf("\nPRESS ANY KEY TO TRY AGAIN");
                    getch();
                    break;
                }     
            }
            while(ch!=6);          
  return 0; 
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Please at least *try* to format your code sensibly.

Comment: Your code has many mistakes and some of your code dosen't make any sense...

Comment: `printf("\n\n\t\tTHANK YOU FOR USING THE SOFTWARE BY:\n\n\tBIJAY PURI\n\n\tBHANU POUDEL\n\n\tNRIPASH AYER...");`...please tell me it's not a _copied_ homework..

Answer (score 3):

Put your `do..while` loop outside `switch` case.

Hint: You might have solved it yourself if you had indented your code properly.

Correct Syntax:

```
do 
  {

    //do something
        switch (variable)
        {
        //case 
        break;
        }
  }
while (condition)
```

---

EDIT:

Below is a working version [on linux] of your code. Please notice the changes carefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char choice,name[40],date[40],note[500];
        int password;
        int ch;

        printf("\n\n\t\tMAIN MENU:");
        printf("\n\n\tADD RECORD\t[1]");
        printf("\n\tVIEW RECORD\t[2]");
        printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
        printf("\n\tDELETE RECORD\t[4]");
        printf("\n\tEDIT PASSWORD\t[5]");
        printf("\n\tEXIT\t\t[6]");


        do{
        printf("\n\n\tENTER YOUR CHOICE:");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
                switch(ch)

                {
                        case 1:
                            printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]\n");
                            printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]\n");
                            printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]\n");
                            printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]\n");

                                break;
                        case 2:    
                                printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");                      
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                                break;
                        case 4:
                                printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                                break;
                        case 5:            
                                printf("\n\tEDIT RECORD\t[3]");
                                break;
                        case 6:
                                printf("\n\n\t\tTHANK YOU FOR USING THE SOFTWARE BY:\n\n\tBIJAY PURI\n\n\tBHANU POUDEL\n\n\tNRIPASH AYER...");
                                exit(0);
                        default:
                                printf("\nYOU ENTERED WRONG CHOICE..");
                                printf("\nPRESS ANY KEY TO TRY AGAIN");
                                break;
                }
        } while(1);          //no need to check conditions here, redundant.

        return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Also, user can't enter a new value if its one of the condition values (1-5).

Comment: @jbutler483 was editing. addressed that in my code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `do while` and `switch` curly braces are tangled.

This is what you have:

```
switch (variable)
{
    do {

    }
}
while (condition);
```

and this is the correct way:

```
do {
    switch (variable)
    {

    }
}
while (condition);
```

Also you must put `getch` before the `return` instruction otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It always closing my program i clearly check and revise my code
this is my last code         }
    } while(ch!=0);           

    return 0 ; 
    getch();
}         but it notworking always closing on my program.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like

```
do{
   //read your option
   scanf("%d",&ch);
   //do something with that option you get
   switch(option){
   }
}while(option != 6);
```

And this because always have to think , what actions you need to repeat